# why when i open existing realm database is always zero result

Tags: swift, realm, xcode8

why when i open existing  realm database is always zero result

```
 func chekDB() {
    let bundleDB = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Conversio", ofType: "realm")
    let desPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let fullDesPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: desPath).appendingPathComponent("Conversio.realm")
    let fullDestPathString = String(describing: fullDesPath)
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fullDesPath.path){
        print("Database file is exis !")
        print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bundleDB!))
    }else{
        do{
            try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundleDB!, toPath: fullDesPath.path)
        }catch{
            print("error encured while copying file to directori \(fullDestPathString)")
        }
    }
}
```

and when i call it with

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let data = realm.object(some.self)
print(data.count) // => 0 ??
```

Comment: is there any value or elements in realm?

Comment: yes ... in the database realm file

Comment: Previously I moved from SQLite database to Realm. And I moved the Realm file to another project.

Comment: Make sure realm file you're trying to open contains data. You can inspect it with [Realm Browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases).

Comment: print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL! ) use this you can get the file path then check is there any data in realm

Answer (score 0):

You should specify realm file path to open your realm file:

```
let realm = try! Realm(fileURL: YOUR_REALM_FILE_URL)
```

Lear more at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms